# The most lightweight way to dynamically load different views at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout

Sometimes I may need to load different views to one page, usually I created a container element at layout xml file, e.g.,

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content/>
```

The above `FrameLayout` could be a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or whatever. At the runtime, use this container to be root of dynamically added view. It worked fine but this container layout incremented one level of view hierarchy.

There is `merge` element in xml, but can't programmatically merge layouts.

There is `ViewStub`, still can't programmatically load with different layouts or views

I'm curious if there is any more lightweight way?

Comment: use fragments. they can be easily created, easily destroyed, easily replaced and are reusable

Comment: do you want to create views programmatically, like a `new ImageView(context)`, etc?

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov, sometimes I did

Comment: @HirakChhatbar, fragment is one choice, I forgot to mention, but there might be some tiny views, then I don't want to use fragment at that moment. Fragment lifecycle is a mess

Comment: i understood what u want and still will recommend fragments. it actually isnt a mess. i too was afraid of fragmetns initially. u need to invest couple of days completely on fragments and u will be done. u can add tiny views also with fragments.  refer to fragment tutorials of slidenerd. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo

Comment: @HirakChhatbar, I always created custom views (with business logic) which acts like kind of fragment, except lifecycle things. Anyway I'm not totally anti-fragments person :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<merge>` correctly, but you have to make sure that your `inflate` calls has a parent specified, and the inflated layout must be added to that parent (pass `true` as the 3rd param):

```
LinearLayout somecontainer = ...
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_merge_layout, somecontainer, true);
```

Then you will not get any additional depth, all children of `<merge>` will be added to `somecontainer` directly.

Comment: If 'merge' used, could the layout xml be inflated into any type of container? I mean, if container is LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or any other types.